# /myproject.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream,

Tags: linux, nginx, ubuntu-18.04, uwsgi, flask

Iam serving flask by nginx and uwsgi but i am getting a permission error

Iam newbie with nginx

**/var/log/nginx/error.log**

```
 *1 connect() to unix:///usr/share/nginx/html/myproject/myproject.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.100.137, server: 192.168.100.137, request: "GET /myproject/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:///usr/share/nginx/html/myproject/myproject.sock:", host: "192.168.100.137
```

**/etc/nginx/sites-available/myproject**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 192.168.100.137;

    location  /myproject {

        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:///usr/share/nginx/html/myproject/myproject.sock;
    }
}
```

**/etc/systemd/system/myproject.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=uWSGI instance to serve myproject
After=network.target

[Service]
User=usama
Group=www-data
PrivateTmp=false
PrivateTmp=No
WorkingDirectory=/usr/share/nginx/html
Environment="PATH=/usr/share/nginx/html/myproject/venv/bin"
ExecStart=/usr/share/nginx/html/myproject/venv/bin/uwsgi --ini myproject.ini
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**/usr/share/nginx/html/myproject/myproject.ini**

```
[uwsgi]
module = wsgi:app

master = true
processes = 5

socket = myproject.sock
chmod-socket = 666
vacuum = true
die-on-term = true
```

hope find an anwser

Comment: `uwsgi_pass unix:///usr/share/nginx/html/myproject/myproject.sock;` should be `uwsgi_pass unix:/usr/share/nginx/html/myproject/myproject.sock;`. See [`uwsgi_pass`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_uwsgi_module.html#uwsgi_pass)

Comment: both are the same

Comment: i am still getting this error

Comment: Change `socket` config value on your uWSGI config from `myproject.sock` to `/usr/share/nginx/html/myproject/myproject.sock`.